# Contrast coding scheme seems to affect whether LME model will converge, but why?

Tags: r, lme4

I wasn't sure whether I should post this question here or on CrossValidated, so please let me know if you think it doesn't belong here!

I recently ran a 2x2 experiment with factors version (A, B) and word type (IC, SC). I analysed my data using the lme4 package (version 1.1-7) and hand-coded my categorical predictors in Excel (just because I find that easier, nothing against R). I am currently preparing a pre-registration for a bigger 5x2 experiment (with 5 versions instead of 2). For the analysis of this experiment, it would make more sense to use dummy coding for version, as there is one "basic" version of the experiment and I would like to compare the other 4 versions against the basic version.

Since I find it difficult to wrap my head around the consequences of using one type of coding scheme versus using another, I wanted to see if using dummy coding instead of deviation coding would affect the significance of any main (or interaction) effects, by which I mean the main effect you get by removing all of the predictors associated with a certain factor (e.g. all 4 predictors that code for version) and compare this model to the full model to get a significance value for the main effect of that factor (and similarly for the interaction, as there would be 4 predictors that code the interaction).

So I tried to use dummy coding for my 2x2 experiment. However, whereas the LME model with the deviation-coded predictors converges without any problems, the LME model with the dummy-coded predictors won't converge. Below is (some of) my code.

```
## coding schemes

#     deviation coding    dummy coding
# A:  -0.5                1
# B:  +0.5                0
# IC: -0.5                1
# SC: +0.5                0
```

This model uses deviation coding to predict inverse-transformed RTs. It converges and looks fine. I've included the summary of the model just in case.

```
> RT.dev<-lmer(invRT ~ 1 + type.dev * version.dev
         + (1 + type.dev|QualtricsID) 
         + (1 + version.dev|item), 
         data = ICandSConly, REML = FALSE)
> summary(RT.dev)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  
    t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom 
    ['merModLmerTest']
Formula: invRT ~ 1 + type.dev * version.dev + (1 + type.dev | QualtricsID)
    + (1 + version.dev | item)
Data: ICandSConly

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
     9.1     69.9      6.5    -12.9     1847 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8402 -0.6158  0.0832  0.6524  3.3694 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
 item        (Intercept)  0.0041857 0.06470       
             version.code 0.0006977 0.02641  0.73 
 QualtricsID (Intercept)  0.0068272 0.08263       
             type.code    0.0016339 0.04042  -0.13
 Residual                 0.0535732 0.23146       
Number of obs: 1858, groups:  item, 112; QualtricsID, 18

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            1.52845    0.02123 21.33000  71.992  < 2e-16 ***
type.dev              -0.03339    0.01894 40.22000  -1.763 0.085503 .  
version.dev            0.22991    0.04073 18.13000   5.644 2.29e-05 ***
type.dev:version.dev  -0.12246    0.02932 17.43000  -4.176 0.000604 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                       (Intr) typ.dv vrsn.d
type.dev               -0.058              
version.dev             0.118 -0.005       
type.dev:version.dev   -0.006  0.158 -0.079
```

Then this model uses dummy coding, but does not converge and gives me two warning messages.

```
> RT.dum<-lmer(invRT ~ 1 + type.dum * version.dum
             + (1 + type.dum|QualtricsID) 
             + (1 + version.dum|item), 
             data = ICandSConly, REML = FALSE)
Warning messages:
  1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
    unable to evaluate scaled gradient
  2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
    Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
> summary(RT.inv.dummy)
Model is not identifiable...
summary from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['merModLmerTest']
Formula: invRT ~ 1 + type.dummy + version.dummy + interaction.dummy +
    (1 + type.dummy | QualtricsID) + (1 + version.dummy | item)
Data: ICandSConly

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    44.8    105.6    -11.4     22.8     1847 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7637 -0.6233  0.0926  0.6728  3.4959 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name          Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 item        (Intercept)   0.000000 0.00000       
             version.dummy 0.002630 0.05129   NaN 
 QualtricsID (Intercept)   0.006796 0.08244       
             type.dummy    0.001469 0.03832  -0.11
 Residual                  0.056314 0.23731       
Number of obs: 1858, groups:  item, 112; QualtricsID, 18

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)        1.59932    0.03140   50.93
type.dummy         0.09270    0.02127    4.36
version.dummy     -0.17037    0.04269   -3.99
interaction.dummy -0.12132    0.03026   -4.01

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) typ.dm vrsn.d
type.dummy  -0.271              
versin.dmmy -0.736  0.199       
intrctn.dmm  0.191 -0.703 -0.289
convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

I figured using a different coding scheme shouldn't matter, so this confused me rather a lot. Could anyone explain to me why the model that uses the dummy-coded predictors won't converge? I've tried Google-ing it and searching on SO, but I haven't found anything so far about the style of coding affecting whether or not a model will converge. Thank you all very much in advance!

Eva

Comment: what are the parameter estimates when you use the dummy coding?  Are they equivalent to the parameters from the deviation coding?

Comment: No, they are different, as you can see in the summary I just added.

Comment: I am finding this same issue with a growth curve analysis with time-binned data as I consider various levels of complexity with my random effects. In many cases, deviation-coding allows convergence/no warnings, but the same models fit with dummy coding give warnings about singularity, and I do not get LRT results or profile CI estimates for some (or all) terms when using dummy coding. For my experiment, deviation coding does not make sense, but dummy does.